# How to Filter the NSMutableArray containing the NSDictionary in ios

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nspredicate, nsmutabledictionary

HI everyone in my projects i'm having a NSMutable Array Containing a NSDictionary in that

i done filter by key & values

```
 NSPredicate * prediStr=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"BusAC == %@",@"AC"];
 filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[totDictArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:prediStr]];
```

then i filtered the key with array value

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.count; i++)
 {
   NSPredicate * prediStr=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TravelsName IN %@",arr[i]];
   filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[filteredArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:prediStr]];                
 }
```

,here my problem is i want to filter the array value containing Dictionary here my array values:

```
(
        {
        Boarding =         (
                        {
                "board_id" = 0;
                "board_value" = "CMBT Omini BS";
            },
                        {
                "board_id" = 1;
                "board_value" = CMBT;
            },
                        {
                "board_id" = 2;
                "board_value" = Thambaram;
            }
        );
        BusAC = "A/C";
        BusFare = 550;
        BusType = "Semi Sleeper";
        TravelsName = "ABC Travels";
    },
        {
        Boarding =         (
                        {
                "board_id" = 0;
                "board_value" = CMBT;
            },
                        {
                "board_id" = 1;
                "board_value" = Guindy;
            },
                        {
                "board_id" = 2;
                "board_value" = Thambaram;
            }
        );
        BusAC = "A/C";
        BusFare = 600;
        BusType = Seater;
        TravelsName = "Arulmigu Aandal Azahagar Madurai Express";
    },
        {
        Boarding =         (
                        {
                "board_id" = 0;
                "board_value" = "CMBT Omini BS";
            },
                        {
                "board_id" = 1;
                "board_value" = CMBT;
            },
                        {
                "board_id" = 2;
                "board_value" = Thambaram;
            }
        );
        BusAC = "A/C";
        BusFare = 1250;
        BusType = Sleeper;
        TravelsName = "GSP  Travels";
    },
        {
        Boarding =         (
                        {
                "board_id" = 0;
                "board_value" = CMBT;
            },
                        {
                "board_id" = 1;
                "board_value" = Guindy;
            },
                        {
                "board_id" = 2;
                "board_value" = Velachery;
            }
        );
        BusAC = "Non A/C";
        BusFare = 350;
        BusType = "Semi Sleeper";
        TravelsName = "Madura  Travels";
    }
)
```

in this i want filter the

```
 Boarding Values
(
    CMBT,
    Guindy

) & 
BusAC Value A/C
```

Help me

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to sort array of dictionaries, and in each dictionary you need sort some internal array. So in fact you need to modify each internal array with results of local sort, and then sort this global array.
In fact, NSPredicate does not modify elements, so I propose to "unpack" this dictionary into:

```
.....
{
    BusAC = "A/C";
    BusFare = 600;
    BusType = Seater;
    TravelsName = "Arulmigu Aandal Azahagar Madurai Express";
    "board_id" = 0;
    "board_value" = CMBT;
},
    {
    BusAC = "A/C";
    BusFare = 600;
    BusType = Seater;
    TravelsName = "Arulmigu Aandal Azahagar Madurai Express";
    "board_id" = 1;
    "board_value" = Guindy;
},
.....
```

To make it easier, I recommend to use [LinqToObjectiveC](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC), or any other solution.

```
 NSArray *unpackedArray = [testArray linq_selectMany:^id(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *item) {
    NSMutableDictionary *resultDic = [item mutableCopy];
    [resultDic removeObjectForKey:@"Boarding"];
    NSArray *boarding = item[@"Boarding"];
    return [boarding linq_select:^id(NSDictionary *item) {
        return [item linq_Merge:resultDic];
    }];
}];
NSLog(@"unpacked: %@", unpackedArray );
```

and then you can filter it as you want, with predicate, or something else

```
unpackedArray = [[unpackedArray linq_where:^BOOL(NSDictionary *item) {
    return [@[@"CMBT", @"Guindy"] containsObject:item[@"board_value"]];
}] linq_where:^BOOL(NSDictionary *item) {
    return [item[@"BusAC"] isEqualToString:@"A/C"];
}];
NSLog(@"unpacked: %@", unpackedArray );
```